# "Хлебные крошки" из дерева

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно ввести в input название родителей по порядку пытаюсь сделать так:

```js
$('.boxsct').each(function(){
  var clnfre = $(this).data('catParentId');
  if (clnfre != "") {
    console.log('----' + clnfre);
    if ($(this).parents('.boxsct').attr('data-cat-full-id')) {
      arrindt = $(this).parents('.boxsct').children('label').text();
      console.log('--' + arrindt);
      $(this).children('input').val(arrindt);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 edit-view-field " type="varchar" field="custom_drop_fields" colspan="3">
<span id="custom_drop_fields_span">
<div class="inp" style="margin-left: 15px;"><div class="boxsct " data-cat-full-id="168" data-cat-parent-id="">
<label>Посуда: </label>
<input type="text" name="name_cat_resp[]">
<div class="inp" style="margin-left: 15px;"><div class="boxsct " data-cat-full-id="e1334bf5-5709-fe7a-6653-5861f2698f04" data-cat-parent-id="168">
<label>Тарелки:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name_cat_resp[]">
</div></div></div><div class="boxsct " data-cat-full-id="13" data-cat-parent-id="">
<label>Для дома: </label>
<input type="text" name="name_cat_resp[]">
<div class="inp" style="margin-left: 15px;"><div class="boxsct " data-cat-full-id="26896c75-3046-ae3e-c997-585cbc28f7e0" data-cat-parent-id="13">
<label>Мебель: </label>
  <input type="text" name="name_cat_resp[]">
<div class="inp" style="margin-left: 15px;"><div class="boxsct " data-cat-full-id="b3ecb55d-7cca-b9ec-d538-586200857578" data-cat-parent-id="26896c75-3046-ae3e-c997-585cbc28f7e0">
  <label>Диваны: </label>
<input type="text" name="name_cat_resp[]">
</div></div></div></div></div><div class="boxsct " data-cat-full-id="23" data-cat-parent-id="">
<label>Для автомобиля: </label>
  <input type="text" name="name_cat_resp[]"><br>
</div></div></span>
</div>
```

Выводится соответственно в обратном порядке, т.е. от ребенка к родителю, а нужно наоборот (чтоб получилось что то вроде хлебных крошек).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//arrindt = arrindt.split(":").reverse().join(":");
var items = [];
$(this).parents('.boxsct').children('label').each(function(index){
  items.push($(this).text());
});
var arrindt = items.reverse().join("");
$(this).children('input').val(arrindt);
```

Comment: Спасибо, но в тексте (названии) к сожалению может тоже находится двоеточие, пример выше (простите за тавтологию ) для примера.

Comment: @KonstantinT. А пожалуйста!